Possible upgrade to MathJax v$3$/v$4$
Similar to that of Possible MathJax upgrade on the MathOverflow meta site, this question is to let everyone here know, but particularly those who aren't often on the network Meta site, that there's a post there, i.e., Upgrade plans for MathJax v3/v4, to inform everybody that SE is currently working on upgrading from MathJax v$2$ to v$3$ initially, then to v$4$. This is still in the experimental phase, with the default being that it's not being used. Anybody who's interested can enable this in their profile preferences page.
The network Meta question currently has $5$ answers, with $3$ of them being mine. I've also noticed several other issues which I haven't reported yet (although I might later if nobody else has done it in the meantime). The main one is that there's sometimes a problem with converting and displaying some of, or all, of the MathJax equations. For me, this happened only very rarely with v$2$, but I estimate that it's happening about $5$-$10$% of the time with v$3$ (your mileage may vary, depending on things like the browser used, OS, machine load, etc.). However, this frequency depends, at least to some extent, on the particular post. There's one post that I was testing with where it didn't display properly almost half of the time, even after I waited for several minutes, just in case it was just being slow to update. Nonetheless, a screen refresh has fortunately always resolved this problem for me.
There are only, as far as I now know, KyleMit's answer and other answer (thanks to Martin's comment about this), as well as several comments (and a deleted answer) to A Limited Advertising Test on this Site, where this experimental MathJax version is mentioned. As the biggest MathJax enabled site, I wanted to help ensure more people here are aware of it, so I thought that a new question might help to do that. Also, there are undoubtedly quite a few other additional issues to be detailed, with having more people using the new version meaning they are more likely to be found and reported on.

See also: MathJax out of date and Switch to MathJax version 3? - in particular, KyleMit's answers posted not too long ago. (Still, the new question probably gets noticed by more user if it gest into the community bulletin.)

@MartinSleziak Thanks for listing those $2$ answers in your comment. I've updated my post to include them. Also, I agree that having this post appear in the community bulletin, such as if it became a "featured" post, would also help a lot to get more of our community members to be aware of this issue.

@MartinSleziak FYI, your question & answer at Riemann integral using piecewise linear and $C^1$-functions as upper functions don't render any MathJax at all with MathJax v$3$, due to \begingroup. This is explicitly mentioned in Upgrading from v2 to v3 - MathJax 3.2 documentation, about $80$% down the page in the "Not Yet Ported to Version 3" section, where it says "The begingroup and mediawiki-texvc TeX extensions haven’t been ported to version $3$ yet, but should be in the future". ...

@MartinSleziak (cont.) I'm unsure about what \begingroup does, the difficulty if this needs to not be used, how often you've used it, the extent it has been used in other members' posts, etc. The documentation says, regarding porting, that it "should be in the future", but no indication of how likely, or when. As you most likely know a lot more about this than I do, you may wish to post an answer to the network Meta question at Upgrade plans for MathJax v$3$/v$4$ explaining about your knowledge about, and perception of, this problem if we upgrade.

Here is a post relevant for begingroup: The scope of \newcommand is the entire page The answer posted by a member of staff says that since 2019 every post and every comment is enclosed between \begingroup and \endgroup.

@MartinSleziak Thanks for letting me know about that. It's most interesting. My best guess is that this new problem has something to do with the \begingroup being explicitly in the post, e.g., near the end of this answer, and its first comment, both appear normally in v$2$. However, with v$3$ beta, the equation now appears as this, while the comment shows instead as this, including with each cos now appearing similar to a smile with $2$ small "eyes", & a dot, above it.
