A table, containing MathJax symbols, that would be great.
I just edited this question.
While doing that, I introduced a table, like this one:



a
b




11
22



This is created as follows:
|   a|   b|
|----|----|
|  11|  22|

I don't like the font, so let's turn this into MathJax:



a
b




$11$
$22$



This is created as follows:
|     a|     b|
|------|------|
|  $11$|  $22$|

Then, I thought "Wouldn't it be far better putting the entire table in MathJax instead of every single value?", so I tried but I failed:
$|   a|   b|
|----|----|
|  11|  22|$
=>Oops, this is not displayed as a table anymore :-(
This failure is created as:
$|   a|   b|
|----|----|
|  11|  22|$

Wouldn't it be great if MathJax was extended with the understanding of tables (and other StackExchange formatting)? :-)

Using array is not a satisfactory solution for you?
$$\begin{array}{|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{a} & \textbf{b} \\hline
11 & 22 \\hline
\end{array}$$

@MartinSleziak: you know how it goes: you see some information and you decide to put it into a table. Once this done, you realise you want this in MathJax. Do you really need to reformat the whole thing?

If you want changes made to MathJax then this is definitely the wrong place to be asking -- you need to contact whoever is maintaining and developing MathJax.

@postmortes: I have no idea who is the developer of MathJax, I'm just hoping that it has foreseen extensions. StackExchange might use such an extension for allowing markdown formatting. (Or am I being unrealistic here? :-) ) I have honestly no idea who is responsible for MathJax and its applications (Math.StackExchange or the original StackExchange). In case this is handled by the regular StackExchange, it's ok to migrate my question there.

@MartinSleziak: what's the format for a MathJax table? Is it far different than the regular markdown table formatting? (Maybe just put your array between backticks)

https://www.mathjax.org (google would have told you that) is the 'owner' of MathJax to the extent that there is one.  It's not part of StackExchange or any of its sites.  This is simply not the place to be asking for changes to this.

@postmortes: why not? The website you described, mentions quite some extensions. I have no idea how MathJax is installed/configured/... here on Math.StackExchange or on StackExchange on general. I'm just wondering about the possibilities to add markdown to MathJax here on the site (or on StackExchange in general).

@Dominique You could have easily copied the code from the first comment. In any case, I used $$\begin{array}{|l|l|}  \hline    \textbf{a} & \textbf{b} \\\hline    11 & 22 \\\hline  \end{array}$$ to get
$$\begin{array}{|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{a} & \textbf{b} \\hline
11 & 22 \\hline
\end{array}.$$ (I am not sure whether it is possible to put source as "multiline" in a comment - this can be done in a post.) See also: Is it possible to see the source for a comment?

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37825/possible-upgrade-to-mathjax-v3-v4 is probably what you look at then.

@MartinSleziak: oops. That's quite different than the general StackExchange table markdown. I guess you understand my question now?

Why do you need an entire table in MathJax? They're not intended for use as arrays the way MathJax already supports, and can obviously contain MathJax formulae where needed, this doesn't seem usefully appropriate in any context beyond "I want it that way".
